# Getting 403 when executing request from amazon server

Tags: c#, webrequest

Very same code works fine from other locations, but whenever is run from amazon server it gets 403. 
We tried "everything":

- checking with postman
- copying cookies
- copying / not copying the headers. 
  whatever we do we get 403 when code / request is run from amazon server. What is even more interesting: browsers work fine (you can get to the same link from any browser without any errors). So the conclusion is like "something blocks requests that are not sent with the browser and we can't impersonate aby browser".


  thanks in advance!

PS as far what i know it's fine from some other hosting services, only Amazon seems to be blocked. 
Requests are not passed from any app / any language, including Postman but they're fine when any browser is used. So it's like "something" detects the original source of request and if request comes from amz "it" blocks the request. Everything is fine when not used from amz servers)

Answer (score 1):

You can send your request to https://requestbin.com/ to analyze better what is going out from the Program and then change the missing parameters.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately gives no new information. Request bin is also hosted on Amz as far as i see and when i use it reponse is same: 403 with no trace "what's up". 
what's really bizarre is the fact that requests do not work under postman, C# code, any other code, but they DO work when using any browser.

Comment: Try creating a simple dump server as a requestbin then